# How can I run a custom validation against a different key in my schema?

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

I'm using Joi to validate user-submitted form data. The data contains bank details: the relevant ones here are `accountNumber` and `sortCode`. I need to take the value of both inputs and run them through an external API to confirm they are valid together.

I'm struggling though to write a custom Joi extension which can get the value of another field in the data. Here's a simplified version of what I've tried:

```
const baseJoi = require('joi');

const bankDetails = joi => {
    return {
        name: 'bankDetails',
        base: joi.number().required(),
        rules: [
            {
                name: 'accountNumber',
                params: {
                    number: joi.number().required()
                },
                validate(params, value, state, options) {
                    console.log(value); // returns 12-34-46 (sortCode)
                    console.log(params.number); // returns a [Function: ref] object
                    console.log(state.parent.accountNumber); // returns 88888888, but feels "wrong"
                }
            }
        ]
    };
};

const Joi = baseJoi.extend([bankDetails]);

const validateBankDetails = () => {
    return Joi.bankDetails().accountNumber(Joi.ref('accountNumber')).required();
};

const schema = Joi.object({
    accountNumber: Joi.number().required(),
    sortCode: validateBankDetails(),
});
```

I know I can use `Joi.ref()` inside Joi's own validators (eg. something like `Joi.number().less(Joi.ref('max'))`) but here I need to take the *value* of that key (`accountNumber`) and pass it through to another function (along with the `sortCode` value). Is there a Joi-approved way of doing this? I can get the value I want from the `state` parameters but this feels a bit of an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using a `custom` [method](https://hapi.dev/module/joi/api/?v=17.1.1#anycustommethod-description) on a plain old Joi object instead of an extension?  I think it might get you what you're looking for in a more straightforward manner:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  accountNumber: Joi.number().required(),
  sortCode: Joi.number().required(),
})
  .custom((obj, helpers) => {
    // you have access to the full object above.
    const { accountNumber, sortCode } = obj;

    // Do your validation
    const isValid = doSomething(accountNumber, sortCode);

    if (!isValid) {
      throw new Error('Invalid input');
    }

    // Just pass the object on through if things work.
    return obj;
  });
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Worth noting, if you need to use an external api, you need to use any.external(), rather than any.custom() in order to use async methods.

Comment: However, this does not register the error for a specific property.

Answer (score 1):

this might be a long-shot and probably already solved. but you can get access to the form state through the helpers variable.

```
const customValidation  = (value, helpers) => {
  const { state: { ancestors: [{ dataFromYourForm }] } } = helpers;
  // some validation logic and errors
}
```